# Force NuGet Commandline List to NOT use Wildcards

Tags: nuget, msbuild-task

I'm trying to use the NuGet command line to get the latest version of a package in a repo as part of an MSBuild task. Unfortunately there are three packages which all start with the same thing, for example:

```
MyCorp.ThirdPartyServices
MyCorp.ThirdPartyServices.DB
MyCorp.ThirdPartyServices.OtherStuff
```

Therefore the command

```
nuget.exe list -Source http://mycorp.repo/nuget MyCorp.ThirdPartyServices
```

Returns all three entries as I'm assuming it's internally adding a wildcard to the end of the search term. Whilst I can deal with this, I'd rather not have to. Is there any way to search for an exact package name or do I just have to suck it up and parse whatever comes out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a special search syntax to filter the result. The following works on nuget.org:

```
nuget.exe list packageid:NUnit
```

This just returns the single NUnit package.

Here I am using NuGet v2.

Comment: Confirmed this works against the public feed but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with a basic feed created using the Nuget.Server package itself. No idea why but I'm guessing its a bit too lightweight and doesn't support the syntax. We might be moving to ProGet in which case I'll try again with that some time, but for now I'll accept this answer as it's a useful nugget of info I couldn't find documented anywhere else. Cheers.